# showing probability of event is zero

Tags: probability

Suppose $( \Omega, \mathscr{A}, P ) $ is probability space and $X,Y$ two random variables such that $ X = Y $ almost surely. Then, I want to show that if $A$ is borel set, then if $N = X^{-1}(A) \cap ( Y^{-1}(A) )^c $ we have that $P(N) = 0 $. IS this a true result? I am struggling trying to show this even though it may seem as trivial.

Answer (score 1):

As $\{X=Y\}$ has probability one, we have
$$
P(N)=P(N\cap\{X=Y\})+P(N\cap \{X=Y\}^c)=P(N\cap\{X=Y\})=0,
$$
where the last equality follows since $N\cap\{X=Y\}=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$\{X \in A, Y \notin A\} \subset \{X \neq Y\}$$

and a subset of a null set is null